# iPad Front camera in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft return rotated image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, front-camera

I have a problem with the iPad front camera While I'm trying to take a photo the result from

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSLog(@"%d",[chosenImage imageOrientation]); }
```

is 1 which mean : `UIImageOrientationDown`

Changing the orientation to Right or using the back camera return 0 or `UIImageOrientationUp`

Am I missing something ?

Comment: To get image in portrait, you can follow this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419053/image-can-not-upload-in-right-direction/36419357#36419357

Comment: No I want the image in landscape mode. The returned image is rotated 180 degree.

Comment: There is a method used in above link..you can modify that method as per your need.